# Azure C# Bot Cards Issue 401

Tags: c#, azure, web, bots, chatbot

I Get the Example SDK For C#.
When I tried to run the CardsBot Example I get the error 401.
But when I run the EchoBot Its works for me.

I am using Bot Framework Emulator, to get the output from the bot.
So what is it can be the issue ?
Some examples Work for me and Some Examples just don't want to work...

Best,
Stav.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Robbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11114129/robbo) posting your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133974/how-do-i-resolve-a-401-on-my-azure-web-app-bot) as an answer to help other community members .

"You can  try to delete the app service and deploy it again."

Or ,You can also check an alternative way to resolve unauthorized issue using Azure portal : [Unauthorized Bot Service from Web Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361412/unauthorized-bot-service-from-web-chat/49377915#49377915)